# CSS make left side fixed postion inside section

Tags: css

I have this section of code:

```
<section id="home-about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h2>Family-owned and operated</h2>
                <h3>A business rooted in hard work and integrity.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0px;">
                        <img src="images/home-about.webp" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row equal">
                    <div class="col-md-6 left">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed orci porttitor, tincidunt quam in, sagittis leo. Nam sed hendrerit sem. Donec euismod, nisi in posuere eleifend, turpis turpis tincidunt mauris, quis commodo eros nisl sed felis. Nullam lobortis metus quam, eget congue ante efficitur vel. Sed ultricies lorem sed est tristique congue.</p>
                        <p>Sed sagittis hendrerit lectus sit amet ornare. Proin vulputate, sapien vitae ullamcorper consequat, dui nunc malesuada augue, nec malesuada ex quam quis purus. Integer volutpat sollicitudin massa dapibus euismod. Integer feugiat elit nec tellus tempus luctus.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 right">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0px;">
                        <img src="images/home-about-bottom.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a href="#">Get to Know Us</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

What I am trying to do is make the left side in a fixed position inside the section so you can see it as you scroll (hope the makes sense) (starts at the top, ends at the bottom)

How would I do that? I tried setting the section to relative and the h2 as fixed with top 0, but it does not stay inside the section.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem, you can add **class="sticky-top"** to your preferred point to be sticky. you mentioned you want to control the sticky part that how much to be sticky and comes by scrolling, so for this case you just need to check your parent row class (I mean **div class="row"**).
Whenever it finishes, then your scroll will stop.
Please check the example and I add some junk codes just for test to see the scrolling.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <section id="home-about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="sticky-top">
                        <h2>Family-owned and operated</h2>
                        <h3>A business rooted in hard work and integrity.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0px;">
                            <img src="images/home-about.webp" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row equal">
                        <div class="col-md-6 left">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed orci porttitor, tincidunt quam in, sagittis leo. Nam sed hendrerit sem. Donec euismod, nisi in posuere eleifend, turpis turpis tincidunt mauris, quis commodo eros nisl sed felis. Nullam lobortis metus quam, eget congue ante efficitur vel. Sed ultricies lorem sed est tristique congue.</p>
                            <p>Sed sagittis hendrerit lectus sit amet ornare. Proin vulputate, sapien vitae ullamcorper consequat, dui nunc malesuada augue, nec malesuada ex quam quis purus. Integer volutpat sollicitudin massa dapibus euismod. Integer feugiat elit nec tellus tempus luctus.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 right">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0px;">
                            <img src="images/home-about-bottom.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a href="#">Get to Know Us</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="home-content" style="margin-top: 250px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="sticky-top">
                        <h2>test</h2>
                        <h3>test2</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0px;">
                            <img src="images/home-about.webp" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row equal">
                        <div class="col-md-6 left">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed orci porttitor, tincidunt quam in, sagittis leo. Nam sed hendrerit sem. Donec euismod, nisi in posuere eleifend, turpis turpis tincidunt mauris, quis commodo eros nisl sed felis. Nullam lobortis metus quam, eget congue ante efficitur vel. Sed ultricies lorem sed est tristique congue.</p>
                            <p>Sed sagittis hendrerit lectus sit amet ornare. Proin vulputate, sapien vitae ullamcorper consequat, dui nunc malesuada augue, nec malesuada ex quam quis purus. Integer volutpat sollicitudin massa dapibus euismod. Integer feugiat elit nec tellus tempus luctus.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 right">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row equal">
                        <div class="col-md-6 left">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed orci porttitor, tincidunt quam in, sagittis leo. Nam sed hendrerit sem. Donec euismod, nisi in posuere eleifend, turpis turpis tincidunt mauris, quis commodo eros nisl sed felis. Nullam lobortis metus quam, eget congue ante efficitur vel. Sed ultricies lorem sed est tristique congue.</p>
                            <p>Sed sagittis hendrerit lectus sit amet ornare. Proin vulputate, sapien vitae ullamcorper consequat, dui nunc malesuada augue, nec malesuada ex quam quis purus. Integer volutpat sollicitudin massa dapibus euismod. Integer feugiat elit nec tellus tempus luctus.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 right">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row equal">
                        <div class="col-md-6 left">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed orci porttitor, tincidunt quam in, sagittis leo. Nam sed hendrerit sem. Donec euismod, nisi in posuere eleifend, turpis turpis tincidunt mauris, quis commodo eros nisl sed felis. Nullam lobortis metus quam, eget congue ante efficitur vel. Sed ultricies lorem sed est tristique congue.</p>
                            <p>Sed sagittis hendrerit lectus sit amet ornare. Proin vulputate, sapien vitae ullamcorper consequat, dui nunc malesuada augue, nec malesuada ex quam quis purus. Integer volutpat sollicitudin massa dapibus euismod. Integer feugiat elit nec tellus tempus luctus.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 right">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row equal">
                        <div class="col-md-6 left">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed orci porttitor, tincidunt quam in, sagittis leo. Nam sed hendrerit sem. Donec euismod, nisi in posuere eleifend, turpis turpis tincidunt mauris, quis commodo eros nisl sed felis. Nullam lobortis metus quam, eget congue ante efficitur vel. Sed ultricies lorem sed est tristique congue.</p>
                            <p>Sed sagittis hendrerit lectus sit amet ornare. Proin vulputate, sapien vitae ullamcorper consequat, dui nunc malesuada augue, nec malesuada ex quam quis purus. Integer volutpat sollicitudin massa dapibus euismod. Integer feugiat elit nec tellus tempus luctus.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 right">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0px;">
                            <img src="images/home-about-bottom.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a href="#">Get to Know Us</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Good Luck!

**Attention1:** I supposed that you're using **Bootstrap** in your code and my change and solution is based on Bootstrap. If you are using another library, it has to be re-check particularly.

**Attention2:** If you want to check the result of code, because of responsiveness, please check it in full page size.